# How to handle file inputs with changing schemas in Talend

Tags: schema, talend

**Questions: How do I continue to process files that differ substantially from a base schema and that trigger tSchemaComplianceCheck errors?**

**Background**

Suppose I have a folder with Customer xls files called `file1,file2,....file1000`. Assume I have imported the file schema into Talend repository and called it `6Columns` and I have the talend job configured to iterate through each of the files and process them

```
1-tFileInput ->2-tSchemaCompliance-6Columns -> 3-tMap ->4-FurtherProcessing
```

1. Read each excel file
2. Compare it to the schema `6Columns`
3. Format the output (rename columns)
4. Take the collection of Customer data and process it more

While processing I notice that the schema compliance is generating errors (`errorCode 16`) which points to a number of files (200) with a different schema `13Columns` but there isn't a way to identify the files in advance to filter then into a subjob

**How do I amend my processing to correctly integrate the files with `13Columns`schema into the process (whats the recommended way of handling) and designing incase other schema changes occur**

```
1-tFileInput ->2-tSchemaCompliance-6Columns -> 3-tMap ->4-FurtherProcessing
                   |
                   |Reject Flow (ErrorCode 16)

                   |Schema-13Columns 
                   |
                   |-> ??
```

Current Thinking When `ErrorCode 16` detected

Option 1 Parallel. Take the file path for the current file and process it against `13Columns` using a new FileInput before merging the 2 flows back into 1

Option 2 Serial. Collect the list of files that triggered the error and process them after I've finished with the compliance files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like below :

[image]

**tFileList** - Read your input repository
**tFileInput** "schema6" - **tSchemaComplianceCheck** : read files as 6-columns schema
**tMap_1** : further processing

In the reject part :

**tMap** after reject link : add a new column containing the filepath that has been rejected
[image]

**tFlowToIterate** : used to get an iterate link, acceptable input for tFileInputDelimited that follows.
**tFileInput** : read data as 13-columns schema. Following components are the same as in part 1.

After that, you can push your data to tHashOutput, in order to read them further in another subjob.

Comment: Are there any downsides to the waterfall/cascading style method you suggest? e.g. if another schema needed to be added (14Columns) or is this the recommended way of handling this kind of situation

Comment: If you have to add other schemas, yes, you'll have to get the reject link from the 2d tSchemaComplianceCheck, and add some more components, to deal with the new schema. Talend is schema-based, so I don't think it's possible to work with the components without knowing schemas first.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just concerned it won't scale very well if the number of schemas to test against increases beyond a handful